# Data request: Multiple networks for multiple observation

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a networked data set for the same set of actors with multiple networks.
These multiple networks may represent different kind of interactions, or the same type of interaction under different conditions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: huh?  I'm suspect 'actor', 'network' and 'interactions' are jargon in a specific community that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: actors = nodes,
network is network (graph if you wish),
interaction = the types of connections between the nodes

Comment: Synonyms aren't helping.  I think UML and Use Cases when I see 'actor'.  I'm going to assume that this has been sitting open for days w/ no requests as no one else has a clue what it is that you're asking for, either.  If you can't explain what it is that you're looking for, explain why it is that you want it and what you're trying to do with it, as we might be able to infer from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CASOS Network Archive](http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/computational_tools/data2.php) has a number of networks that may be of interest. For instance, the [50 Women](http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/computational_tools/datasets/external/50women/index11.php) network tracks friendship networks (three realizations) among 50 adolescent girls.

Another resource, if you're into very large data sets, if the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/), which has social, communication, and citation networks, among others. Some of these are temporal networks.

The [Siena data set](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/siena/siena_datasets.htm) page has temporal networks as well.

Perhaps if you provide a bit more information about what you are specifically looking for, you will get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

May DBLP collaboration dataset could help you.Visit https://aminer.org/billboard/citation .The dataset is a raw text data. You can extract co-authorship and citation relationship from the text.